# How to get values from an array in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 arrays:

```
 A = [AC,DC];
 B = [3,4,4,4];
 c = [1,2,2,2];
```

I need to create a loop to retrieve the values from these array and display in the format:

```
{
  name:AC
  value:{
         one:3 // from B
         two :1, // from C
         },
         {
           one:4, // from B
           two:2   // from C
         }
},
{
       name:DC
        value:{
            one:3 // from B
            two :1, // from C
           },
           {
            one:4, // from B
            two:2   // from C
          }
}
}
```

The arrays are changing ,not consistent .

```
this.A.forEach((item,index)=>{
      this.B.forEach((item1,index2)=>{
        this.multi.push(
          {
            "names":item,
            "value":[
              {
                "one":item1,
                "two":this.c[index2]
              }
          ]
        })
        })
```

i use this for loop , but i did't get the correct format.Any mistake in my code? anything need to change ? Any help will  be appreciated. any other option rather than the for-each loop. I use for each loop for getting all values,because the values in array is changes.And one thing also first array length is not same as second and third array.but array 2 and array 3 will be same.

Comment: B and C have 4 elements each, why does the result only have 2 occurrences of `{one: <element from B>, two: <element from C>}'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```js
let A = ["AC","DC"];
let B = [3,4,4,4].filter((v,i) => [3,4,4,4].indexOf(v) == i);
let C = [1,2,2,2].filter((v,i) => [1,2,2,2].indexOf(v) == i);

let E = A.map(item=>{
  return {'name':item,
   'value':B.map((item,index)=>{
  return {'one':B[index],'two':C[index]}
   })
 } 
})
console.log(E)
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
this.A.forEach((item,index)=>{
    let values:{}[] =[];
    for(let i=0 ; i<Math.min(this.B.length , this.C.length) ; i++){
      values.push(
        {
          "one":this.B[i],
          "two":this.C[i]
        }
      )
    }
    this.multi.push(
          {
            "names":item,
            "value":values
        })
  });
  console.log(this.multi)   
  }
```

working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-j2wbe9)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```js
let A = ["AC","DC"];
let B = [3,4,4,4];
let C = [1,2,2,2];

let result = {};
A.forEach((element) => {
    result[element] = {
        name: element,
        value: B.map((_, index) => {
            return {
                one: B[index],
                two: C[index]
            };
        })
    };
});

console.log(result);
```